# Jquery animation doesn't work on id-specified divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going mad. The question is very simple yet over my comprehension for some reason.
THIS WORK (on every div of the page, even #example):

```
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('div').animate({left: '250px'});
    });
```

BUT THIS NOT:

```
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#example').animate({left: '250px'}); 
    });
```

I'm very confused.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: It sounds like you have more than one `#example` element in your page

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to load? Is your script tag in the head of your html or the end of the body tag? Are you loading the element dynamically? Please provide more code and clarify the issue.
Here's a working example https://jsfiddle.net/kf2okn11/

Comment: I'm working on other things right now, I'll update this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is true. Simply `$('#example')` is not available when its being used. You can check/verify it like

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
   if($('#example') && $('#example').length>0)
   {
     alert("O great i am available, let me show you my animation");
     $('#example').animate({left: '250px'}); 
     alert("Good, animation really worked");
   }
   else
      alert("Error => machine is right, element with id=example is not available yet");
});
```

In error case you just have to make the `#example` available